# How do I pass i=index value from an ionic 4 html file into the .ts file for use in a method?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I have an *ngFor that uses let i=index and works as expected indexing the array.

html

```
  <div *ngFor="let fromItem of listResults let i=index;">
    <ion-item  (click)="openSubsetPage( i )" detail>
      <ion-label>{{fromItem.Name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-badge color="light">{{filter}} / {{listNumber[i].Questions.length}}</ion-badge>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is using the [i] from my html file, inside of my .ts file at line 5 this.filter.  I wish to replace the [0] with [i].  I am unsure of how I can do this.

.ts

```
GetList(){
  this.storage.get(this.value).then((val) => {
    this.listResults = JSON.parse(val);
    this.listNumber = this.listResults;
    this.filter = this.listNumber[0].Questions.filter((c: { input: any; }) => !!c.input).length;
  });
}
```

Comment: Should this method be called when an item is clicked? What about `openSubsetPage()` method? Are they both the same?

Comment: Actually the GetList opens first with ionViewWillEnter() and populates the *ngFor with a list.  the openSubsetPage() opens a new page passing the [ i ].

Comment: I think the purpose of needing `index` is to access that item in the array. When view is loading, you don't have a specific index. If you want to change all `listNumber` items, then why not use a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on `listNumber` to do that?

Comment: I am using the index to access an item in the array.  eg listNumber[i].Questions.length . gives the total number of questions in the array item.  (click)="openSubsetPage( i ) open a new page with array item. etc..

Comment: I understood that. Each list item will have a different `filter` value right? But you had just a single variable `filter` which can only take one value at a time. I think you have to use an array `filter[]` and in template use it as `{{ filter[i] }}`. Or create a new method `getFilter(i)` to calculate the value and use it as `{{ getFilter(i) }}`. I will write an answer if you think this isn't clear enough.

Comment: Yes please.  I gave it a shot on my end and seem to getting trapped in loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to calculate filter values before the view is loaded, then you have to create another array `filter[]` and store the calculated values.

```
let filter[];

GetList() {
  this.storage.get(this.value).then((val) => {
    this.listResults = JSON.parse(val);
    this.listNumber = this.listResults;

    this.listNumber.forEach((item, index) => {
      this.filter[index] = this.listNumber[index].Questions
        .filter((c: { input: any }) => !!c.input).length;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And use it in the template as

`<ion-badge color="light"> {{ filter[i] }} / {{listNumber[i].Questions.length}}</ion-badge>`

Another approach is to create a method which calculates this filter value for a list item at given index.

```
getFilter(index) {
  return this.listNumber[index].Questions.filter((c: { input: any }) => !!c.input).length;
}
```

And use it in the template as

`<ion-badge color="light"> {{ getFilter(i) }} / {{listNumber[i].Questions.length}}</ion-badge>`

Comment: Thanks I was working on something similar to your second example.  Your code is much cleaner.